# Add selectpicker to dynamic input

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel.  Within my controller, I pass my view a list of questions.  I then display things like so

```
@foreach($questions as $q)
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="{{ $q["type"] }}" class="form-control {{ $q["class"] }}">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Now some of these inputs have a type select, and a class which is then set to selectpicker.  Now normally, to set the selectpicker I would use something like this

```
$(function () {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

But because it is being added after the DOM it does not work.  I have searched online and tried suggestions like this

```
$('body').on('focus',".selectpicker", function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('selectpicker') === false )  {
        $(this).selectpicker({
            liveSearch: true
        });
    }
});
```

However the above does not seem to work.  How can I get selectpicker working on dynamically added elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a **input** element with type=select, i.e. this html does NOT work:

```
<input type="select" class="form-control selectpicker">
```

The correct html code for a **select** element is that:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker">
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
   <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry, big mistake from me, wasn't even thinking about how it is done differently in my loop.  Thanks

Comment: np its a common mistake for me also